# Retrieving probe length for linear/quadratic hashing

Tags: java, hash

My assignment deals with hashing and using Horner's polynomial to create a hash function. I have to computer the theoretical probe length using ( 1 + 1/(1-L)**2)/2 (Usuccessful) or (1+1/(1-L))/2 (successful) for Linear probing and then the same for the correct equations that correspond to quadratic probing. I then have to compare the theoretical values with experimental values for load factors 0.1 through 0.9. I am using the find method and searching for 100 random ints to acquire the experimental data. The problem that I am having is that I am not obtaining the correct probeLength value once the find either succeeds or fails.

I create 10000 random ints to fill with and then 100 random ints that I will search for.

```
for(i = 0; i<10000; i++)
{
int x = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * size);  
randomints.add(x);
}
//Make arraylist of 10000 random ints to fill 

for(p = 0; p<100; p++)
{
int x = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * size);
randomintsfind.add(x);
}
```

Later on I have a loop that does the finding and keeps track of how many times the find succeeds or fails. That part of it is working. It is also supposed to keep track of the probeLength for each find and then add them all together so that it can be divided by the number of successes or failures respectively to find out what the average is. That is where I am having a problem. The probeLength isn't being retrieved correctly and I am not sure why.

This is the section of code that calls the find method and keeps track of those variables as well as the creation and filling.

```
HashTableLinear theHashTable = new HashTableLinear(primesize);

  for(int j=0; j<randomintscopy.length; j++)        // insert data
       {
       //aKey = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * size);                                   
       aDataItem = new DataItem(randomintscopy[j]);
       theHashTable.insert(aDataItem);
       }



for(int f = 0; f < randomintsfindcopy.length;f++)
     {

        aDataItem = theHashTable.find(randomintsfindcopy[f]);
        if(aDataItem != null)
        {
        linearsuccess += 1;
        experimentallinearsuccess += theHashTable.probeLength;            
        theHashTable.probeLength = 0;            
        }
        else
        {
        linearfailure += 1;
        experimentallinearfailure += theHashTable.probeLength;
        theHashTable.probeLength = 0;
        }      

     }
```

And then the find method in the HashTableLinear class

```
public DataItem find(int key)    // find item with key
  {
  int hashVal = hashFunc(key);  // hash the key
  probeLength = 1;
  while(hashArray[hashVal] != null)  // until empty cell,
     {                               // found the key?
     if(hashArray[hashVal].getKey() == key)
        return hashArray[hashVal];   // yes, return item
     ++hashVal;                     // go to next cell
     ++probeLength;
     //System.out.println("Find Test: " + probeLength);                 
     hashVal %= arraySize;      // wraparound if necessary
     }
  return null;                  // can't find item
  }
```

When I test printing the probeLength value in the find method and the values that are gotten in the loops calling find are different from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was thinking too hard about this. It resolved it by making a getter and a setter and then setting the value once the item is either found or not found and then retrieving the value with the getter.